# Getting error cannot load such file -- dry/types/compat/form_types (LoadError) while updating bundle in my project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, bundler, dry-validation

Getting error

```
/home/sachin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': cannot load such file -- dry/types/compat/form_types (LoadError)
```

While trying 'bundle update' in one of my project.
i have gem 'dry-validation' in my Gemfile
please let me know what is causing this issue because before bundle update it was working fine but now i can not start my rails project.

After commenting the below code it's working fine.

```
require 'reform/form/dry'
Reform::Form.class_eval do
   include Reform::Form::Dry
end
```

Comment: Can you paste your entire stack trace, so we can have a better idea of what is going on?

Comment: Have you tried installing **gem 'dry-validation'**

Comment: yes this gem(gem 'dry-validation') is already installed in my project

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what versions of the gems you are using but this might be your problem.

https://github.com/trailblazer/reform/issues/500

I used the following in my gemfile, to solve the issue i had. Hopefully version 2.3.0 will be released soon.

`gem 'reform', github: 'trailblazer/reform', branch: 'v2.3.0.rc2'`

Also as a side note, when using 'dry-validation' make sure NOT to use the gem [reform-rails](https://github.com/trailblazer/reform-rails) as stated in the readme